# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS full /boot/

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I've got a Ubuntu server 10.04 that have been running since 10.04. Today when apticron mailed me about new packages the installation of a new kernel update failed due to a full /boot partition. Looking into it I have 226 MB of files in /boot and about 15 different revision of the kernel.

For each version I have the following 6 files:

```
vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic-pae
vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-21-generic-pae
System.map-2.6.32-21-generic-pae
initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic-pae
config-2.6.32-21-generic-pae
abi-2.6.32-21-generic-pae
```

Is it safe to just delete the oldest? Or is there a "proper" method of disposing old versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` show?

Once you get the kernel names you can just `apt-get purge linux-image-version` Just make sure you do not purge your current kernel. The results can be unexpected.

Comment: Lol. +1 for "unexpected"

Answer (score 1):

Remove extra kernel packages via `apt-get` instead of just deleting files from `/boot`.

`apt-get remove` the old `linux-image` packages manually (check `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image` to find what versions are installed).

Comment: Kernel Packages not follow autoremove. Autoremove is only for dependencies that are no longer used by anything installed in the system.

Comment: Good point - edited.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting old, outdated kernels is safe, but use `aptitude purge linux-image-2.6.32-21-generic-pae`, **not** `rm`!
Check what kernels are installed by invoking `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-2`.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tool that automates this chore, in case it helps anyone else: https://github.com/erichs/bootnukem.